# Selenium Grid test Error

Tags: selenium

I have a hub with 2 nodes. My tests are not running with the error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]

This is my tests and my browser...

---

[image]

---

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("test-type");
options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Users\ebrahimpour.l\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FirstPackage\FirstPackage\bin\Debug\chro‌​medriver.exe";

capabilities.SetCapability("chrome.binary", @"C:\Users\ebrahimpour.l\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FirstPackage\FirstPackage\bin\Debug\chro‌​medriver.exe");
capabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);

System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.chrome.‌​driver",
            @"C:\Users\ebrahimpour.l\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FirstPackage\FirstPackage\bin\Debug\chro‌​medriver.exe");

driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\ebrahimpour.l\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FirstPackage\FirstPackage\bin\Debug");

capabilities.SetCapability(capabilities.Platform.ProtocolPlatformType, "WebDriver");
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
capabilities.SetCapability(capabilities.Version, "57");
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "WinNT");
capabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);

RemoteWebDriver rw = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/grid/console"), capabilities);
driver = rw;
baseURL = "http://192.168.10.173:8080/";

verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
```

Comment: Your error message looks like a C# error. Where is StackTrace and code?

Comment: yes,its c#,I debug it and error is in line " RemoteWebDriver rw=new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/grid/console"), capabilities);"

Comment: But what is the StackTrace if you go the error?

Comment: it is what resharper give me about error  "OneTimeSetUp: System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.
  Exception doesn't have a stacktrace "

Comment: TearDown failed for test fixture FirstPackage.AcceptScenario
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'

Comment: TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

Change

`RemoteWebDriver rw = new RemoteWebDriver(newUri("**http://localhost:4444/grid/console**"), capabilities);`

to

`http://localhost:**8888**/**wd/hub**`